# dataTable editor - can there be other way to process data to update?

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, x-editable, datatables-1.10

I'm a student and barely understands anything in the internet.

I've been using X-editable for inline editing, and it worked for me so far, except I needed a feature that unfortunately x-editable does not have. Navigation through 'tab' in keyboard.

You see, the table is a class record, so it consists of about 26 columns and its just feels tiring to click your way in editing through that table.

So I searched around and found dataTables, from datatables.net.

And I was able to make it work, but I do not know how do I connect it with the computations that I do before finally updating the columns.

I mean, this is one of the sample PHP file that dataTable use to fetch and update table:

```
<?php

/*
 * Example PHP implementation used for the index.html example
 */

// DataTables PHP library
include( "../../php/DataTables.php" );

// Alias Editor classes so they are easy to use
use
    DataTables\Editor,
    DataTables\Editor\Field,
    DataTables\Editor\Format,
    DataTables\Editor\Mjoin,
    DataTables\Editor\Options,
    DataTables\Editor\Upload,
    DataTables\Editor\Validate;

// Build our Editor instance and process the data coming from _POST
Editor::inst( $db, 'datatables_demo' )
    ->fields(
        Field::inst( 'first_name' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
        Field::inst( 'last_name' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
        Field::inst( 'position' ),
        Field::inst( 'email' ),
        Field::inst( 'office' ),
        Field::inst( 'extn' ),
        Field::inst( 'age' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::numeric' )
            ->setFormatter( 'Format::ifEmpty', null ),
        Field::inst( 'salary' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::numeric' )
            ->setFormatter( 'Format::ifEmpty', null ),
        Field::inst( 'start_date' )
            ->validator( 'Validate::dateFormat', array(
                "format"  => Format::DATE_ISO_8601,
                "message" => "Please enter a date in the format     yyyy-mm-dd"
            ) )
            ->getFormatter( 'Format::date_sql_to_format',             Format::DATE_ISO_8601 )
        ->setFormatter( 'Format::date_format_to_sql', Format::DATE_ISO_8601 )
)
->process( $_POST )
->json();
```

Look at that. I don't even understand that type of PHP coding. The one I'm used to doesn't use a lot of those arrows.

In X-editable I'm used to having the data handed to me like this.

```
 $name = $_POST['name'] (this is the column name)
 $pk = $_POST['pk'] (this is the primary key)
 $value = $_POST['value'] (well, value)
```

and then with those three I could just throw those in a function, with all of these additional data that I need to include in computations that I  can just fetch by using a bunch of select queries, and also update their related data that will be changed if that certain value was changed.

I don't even know how to make columns that cannot be edited with dataTable editor (read only columns, like name, id etc.)

All I want to know if what I'm used to doing it X-editable, can I use with dataTable editor? And if yes, can I please get an explanation, in a way that I might understand?

Edit: also, in my update query, I'm not just also updating the column that I'm changing in the table, I have this LastEdited and EditedBy column that is supposed to change alongside the current updated value. But the dataTable editor php file, does not seem to have a way for me to make my own update query.

Comment: That kind of coding is what is known as a "fluent interface" or a "fluent API". jQuery in JavaScript relies on this a lot, and probably a good number of other libraries too. Everything on the left of `->` is an object returned from the previous operation, and everything on the right of it is an operation (method) on that object. You don't need to understand the internals too much though to understand what it is doing: each field is created, and then validators are formatters are applied to those fields.

Comment: You may find that using a PHP IDE will give you autocomplete on those classes, making the writing of code much easier. Start with NetBeans (free) or PHPStorm (paid) if you are not already using an IDE.